# Assign DB column in Golang Struct

Tags: go

I have two tables like Retailers and products in database. Retailer has many Products.

They following are the structs I have defined in golang.

```
type Retailers struct {
  Id int 
  Name string
  Products []Product
}

type Product struct {
  Id int 
  Description string
  Url string 
}
```

The following is the query am using to fetch data from Database.

```
select r.id, r.name, p.id, p.description, p.url from retailers r JOIN products on r.id = r.retailer_id
```

Using the above struct and query I wish to form the json as below

```
{
    "id": "DFT",
    "name": "Amazon",
    "products":[
        {
            "id":"APP0001",
            "description":"Iphone5s",
            "url":"www.Iphone5s.com"
        },
        {
            "id":"APP0002",
            "description":"Iphone6s",
            "url":"www.Iphone6s.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this using golang?

Comment: Is your problem about serializing structs or mapping your database records to structs ? these are 2 separate issues.

Comment: @mpm Mapping database records into struct is my problem. My SQL query is returning two rows. I want to form the JSON as mentioned above format.

Comment: You'd better off using a library then, there is a bunch of ORMs listed here : https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#orm , also this one which claims to be close to sql alchemy https://qb.readme.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify struct tags in your struct definition:

```
type Retailers struct {
  Id int `json:"id"`
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Products []Product `json:"products"`
}

type Product struct {
  Id int `json:"id"`
  Description string `json:"description"`
  Url string `json:"url"`
}
```

Comment: My problem is database query is returning two rows. Using that I wants to form the above mentioned json.

Comment: In what format are the rows returned? If your problem is serialising the data maybe you should try using https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp